# For a given Azure AD Service Principal, Get a list of the Azure Objects and Rights

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, azure-service-principal

We are trying to figure out all the rights an Azure Active Directory Service Principal (AADSP) has to objects in our Azure tenant.

For example an AADSP might have:

- Read rights to SharePoint Online site collection A
- Write permissions to SharePoint Online site collection B
- Get permission to Azure Function A
- Post permission to Azure Function B
- Select permissions to SQL Database A

We are hoping that this information to stored in a collection within the Service Principal object. But we have not been able to locate the collection using [Azure Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=applications&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com&headers=W3sibmFtZSI6IkNvbnNpc3RlbmN5TGV2ZWwiLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImV2ZW50dWFsIn1d).

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals

Is our only option to loop thru all Azure objects and check each object's permission and see which Service Principal have been granted rights?

Comment: Could you please include more details on what exactly you need i.e., RBAC roles/API permissions the service principal had?

Comment: All the objects and resources that can fetched using the servicePrincipal API though are mentioned in the properties : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single API to query all sets of permissions given to a SP: application permissions AKA [app roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-app-roles-to-applications), Azure AD directory permissions, and [Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview).

You can obtain application permissions using [MS Graph List appRoleAssignments operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), Azure AD role assignments trough [List unifiedRoleAssignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-list-roleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), and Azure RABC permissions using [Azure REST API Permissions - List For Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/permissions/list-for-resource?tabs=HTTP) operation.

Depending on the set of permissions, you may have to list all resources to find what assignments are available for a given SP.